# Fast Thread-Safe Ruby Hash with strong read bias

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I need some help in understanding Hash in Ruby 1.8.7.

I have a multi-threaded Ruby application, and about 95% of time multiple threads of the application are trying to access a global Hash.

I am not sure if the default Ruby Hash is thread safe. What would be the best way to have a fast Hash but also one that is thread safe given my situation?

Comment: What operations are being performed on this hash? Typically you want to use a mutex to manipulate thread-shared resources.

Comment: Are you trying to read, or change the hash? Reads are safe.

Comment: @theTinMan: I have couple of threads reading from the hash frequently . Writing to the hash happens at a far slower rate. I need to ensure that while trying to synchronize the writes I don't end up slowing the reads.

Comment: I think you'd be safe with a [mutex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Mutex.html) also. Slowing the reads shouldn't be an issue since the write/update would occur very fast. Writing a [benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) would prove/disprove that.

Comment: @Fanatic23, are you interested in seeing an implementation of a read-write lock? If you're not familiar with the term, it is like a mutex, but it allows any number of readers to run concurrently, but only 1 writer (and once a writer gets the lock, all the readers have to wait).

Comment: @AlexD: Sure, and +1 for the answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have put my read-write lock implementation up on StackExchange Code Review to get suggestions for improvement. Readers of this thread, please offer any suggestions you can! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/read-write-lock-implementation-for-ruby

Comment: @Fanatic23, me and 2 other people have tested ReadWriteLock on several Ruby implementations, and I (tentatively) think it may be ready for you to use. Have a look and tell me what you think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a wrapper which protects the `Hash` with a read-write lock. I couldn't find a pre-built Ruby read-write lock implementation (of course JRuby users can use java.util.concurrent.ReentrantReadWriteLock), so I built one. You can see it at:

https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/master/ruby-threads/read_write_lock.rb

Me and two other people have tested it on MRI 1.9.2, MRI 1.9.3, and JRuby. It seems to be working correctly (though I still want to do more thorough testing). It has a built-in test script; if you have a multi-core machine, please download, try running it, and let me know the results! As far as performance goes, it trounces Mutex in situations with a read bias. Even in situations with 80-90% writes, it *still* seems a bit faster than using a Mutex.

I am also planning to do a Ruby port of Java's ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Please note that you must first install the excellent "atomic" gem, from Charles Nutter and MeNTaLGuY!

Comment: @Alex_D I have a similar question to your answer here.  Mainly, I'd rather not use your code, but would rather just use the Atomic library, if indeed that is sufficient.  Can you take a look: [Using Threadsafe Initialization in a JRuby Gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104886/using-threadsafe-initialization-in-a-jruby-gem)

Answer (score 2):

The default Ruby `Hash` is not thread-safe. On MRI and YARV it is "somewhat accidentally thread-safe", because MRI and YARV have a broken threading implementation that is incapable of running two threads simultaneously anyway. On JRuby, IronRuby and Rubinius however, this is not the case.